# Will my Cordova app rejected? Load external data from json response

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, store

I have created one Cordova app for iOS devices but I have a simple question. I load for example in ul list, objects from my API (php) in this way (using Ajax):

```js
$('#abc').html(data.abc2);
```

In server side I have while loops. The result of these loops in json response is something like this ( X number of results):

```html
<li style="margin-left: 31px;">
                        <div class="commmtodeletef>
                          <a href="#" class="item item-content">
                            <div class="item-media" style="width: 51px;"><img style="border-radius: 50%;height: 40px;width: 40px;" src="img" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="item-inner" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 4px;">
                              <div class="item-title-row" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                <div class="item-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 16px;">fname lname</div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="item-text" style="font-size: 15px;color:#000;font-weight: 300;">abc</div>
                              <div class="item-subtitle bottom-subtitle row" style="font-size: 12px;"><div class="timdvcl" style="color: #8e8e93;"><i class="icon ion-md-time"></I>tm</div> <div id="imgdelcomm" data-id="" style="display:none;"><img  src="img/loader.gif" width="20px" /></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

In other words, the loop is executed  on server-side, i get the json response and then I populate the ul, not in the app.js as Ajax loop on success response. Is that a right way or should I use Ajax loops inside my app.js? Will I have a problem when submitting my app on App Store using loops outside of my app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a JSON response here, but I'm just going to answer the main question: There shouldn't be any problem submitting an app. Lots of apps have Ajax calls.

Comment: The requests has to be made through HTTPS, to meet the iOS App [Transport Security requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

Comment: Yes, I know that many apps have Ajax calls. I have seen that many apps get the response from the server, execute the while loop in client-side (app.js) and then load this result in a specific <ul id='name'> . My main question is, Can I execute this while loop in server side  in php language. Is that right? Or should I execute it in client side ($.each .....)?

Comment: For example, I connect to the API via Ajax. I execute the while loops in server (PHP), I store these results in a json $data['listobects'] = $li (the variable $li contains the code that I wrote above X number of results) and then, in Ajax response, I populate the ul list.